# Why is my label not updating variable from different function? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am writing a time clock program. I have built the code, but have had trouble creating a GUI around it. I have entries that takes input and sends them to an outside function with a button event handling for calculation.

Running the program, I do not get a label updating the time. I wonder if it has to do with my textvariables.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os


def show_entry_fields():
    hr= hrvar.get()
    mn = minvar.get()
    sc = secvar.get()
    counter = int(hr)*3600+int(mn)*60+ int(sc)

    mins = int(counter/60)
    hours = int(mins/60)

    hours = IntVar()
    mins = IntVar()
    secs = IntVar()

    while counter > 0:
       counter -= 1
       hours, sec = divmod(counter, 3600)
       mins, sec = divmod(sec, 60)
       printv = StringVar()




       printv = (" %d Hr:, %d Min: %d Sec" % (hours, mins, sec))
       win1 = Tk()
       timeLabel = Label(win1, textvariable= printv).grid(row=7)
       mins= int(counter/60)
       hours = int(mins/60)
       time.sleep(1)
       os.system('cls')
       return
   else:
       finishedLabel = Label(master, text="Time is Up").grid(row=7)
       return


  master = Tk()
  Label(master, text="Enter Hour(s)").grid(row=0)
  Label(master, text="Enter Mins(s)").grid(row=1)
  Label(master, text="Enter Second(s)").grid(row=2)

  hrvar = IntVar()
  minvar = IntVar()
  secvar = IntVar()
  e1 = Entry(master, textvariable = hrvar)
  e2 = Entry(master, textvariable = minvar)
  e3 = Entry(master, textvariable = secvar)

  e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
  e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
  e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

  Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, 
  sticky=W, pady=4)
  Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
  column=1, 
  sticky=W, pady=4)

  mainloop( )
```

Updated code.

```
class Timer:

   def __init__(self, master):
       #self.seconds = 0
       self.time = StringVar()
       self.hr = StringVar()
       self.mins = StringVar()
       self.secs = StringVar()

       self.hr_label = Label(master, text='Enter Hours').pack()
       self.entry_hr = Entry(master, textvariable = self.hr )
       self.entry_hr.pack()

       self.min_label = Label(master, text='Enter Minutes').pack()
       self.entry_min = Entry(master, textvariable = self.mins)
       self.entry_min.pack()



       self.time_label = Label(master, relief='flat', font=("Cambria", 20),
                              textvariable=self.time)
       self.set_time(hours= self.entry_hr.get(), minutes=self.entry_min.get(), seconds = 0)

       self.time.set('00:00:00')
       self.start_button = Button(master, text='Start')
       self.start_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_countdown)

       self.time_label.pack(padx=30, pady=10)
       self.start_button.pack(pady=(10,20))

   def set_time(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
       self.seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
       self.time.set(self.format_time(self.seconds))

   def start_countdown(self, event):
       self.countdown()

   def countdown(self):
       if self.seconds <= 0:
           return
       self.seconds -= 1
       self.time.set(self.format_time(self.seconds))
       self.time_label.after(1000, self.countdown)

   def format_time(self, seconds):
       h = seconds // 3600
       m = (seconds - h*3600) // 60
       s = seconds - h*3600 - m*60
       return '{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(h,m,s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    timer = Timer(root)
    #timer.set_time(hours=0, minutes=20, seconds=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.  You are redefining `printv`, `timeLabel`, and creating a new `Tk()` object at every step in your while loop.  More importantly, you define `printv` as a `StringVar`, but immediately redefine it as a string.  You should define each of them once **outside** of the while loop and then use the `set()` method of `printv`.

---

Here is a very basic timer in Tkinter.  First of all, you should **not** be using `time.sleep` or `while` loops.  The `mainloop` function is already a while loop, and most tkinter objects have a `.after()` method that allows you to call events after a window of time (in milliseconds).

Notice that I created a class to encapsulate my entire UI.  All variables are stored within the class and updated from its methods. The time is set within the script itself (currently to 1 hour, 20 minutes, 10 seconds), though that is easy to modify to accept args from the command line or from text fields in the UI.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Entry

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.seconds = 0
        self.time = StringVar()
        self.time_label = Label(master, relief='flat', font=("Cambria", 20),
                                textvariable=self.time)

        self.hr = StringVar()
        self.hr_label = Label(master, text='Hours:').grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=1)
        self.entry_hr = Entry(master, textvariable=self.hr, width=4)
        self.entry_hr.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.mins = StringVar()
        self.min_label = Label(master, text='Minutes:').grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=1)
        self.entry_min = Entry(master, textvariable=self.mins, width=4)
        self.entry_min.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.secs = StringVar()
        self.secs_label = Label(master, text='Seconds:').grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=1)
        self.entry_sec = Entry(master, textvariable=self.secs, width=4)
        self.entry_sec.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.time.set('00:00:00')
        self.start_button = Button(master, text='Start')
        self.start_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_countdown)

        self.time_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, padx=30, pady=10)
        self.start_button.grid(row=4, columnspan=4, pady=(10,20))

    def set_time(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
        self.seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
        self.time.set(self.format_time(self.seconds))

    def start_countdown(self, event):
        h = self.entry_hr.get()
        m = self.entry_min.get()
        s = self.entry_sec.get()
        h,m,s = map(lambda x: int(x) if x else 0, (h,m,s))
        self.set_time(h,m,s)
        self.countdown()

    def countdown(self):
        if self.seconds <= 0:
            return
        self.time.set(self.format_time(self.seconds))
        self.seconds -= 1
        self.time_label.after(1000, self.countdown)

    def format_time(self, seconds):
        h = seconds // 3600
        m = (seconds - h*3600) // 60
        s = seconds - h*3600 - m*60
        return '{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(h,m,s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    timer = Timer(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How should 'timeLabel' be used, if I am not supposed to redefine it in my while loop?

Comment: `timeLabel` is a Label object with the displayed text linked to the object `printv`.  Changing `printv` will change the value displayed in `timeLabel`.

Comment: Interesting. I have used the set method on `printv`, but my `timeLabel only updates once. It is like the Label is not updating with the`printv`.I have updated my code above.

Comment: It is not updating because you are loosing the reference to the original `timeLabel` object because `timeLabel` is getting redefined with each iteration of your while loop.  Using tkinter relies on understanding object oriented programming, unfortunately tkinter is a really poor environment in which to learn OOP.

Comment: I am having trouble inputing from entry UI to the set_time function you have created. `self.set_time(hours= self.entry_hr.get(), minutes=self.entry_min.get(), seconds = str(0))` It says TyperError must be string not int. I have updated the code above

Comment: The inputs you added are stored as strings.  You must convert them to integers to set the time.  I have updated my code again to include inputs and a conversion.  Keep in mind I kept the inputs as `StringVar`, but in reality you would want to use `IntVar`, which only accepts integer inputs.